# Drupal 8 Localhost is super slow with MAMP on MACOS

Tags: macos, apache, mamp, drupal-8, macos-big-sur

Currently im trying to host a drupal 8 website in my local using MAMP in MAC (bigSur)
but unfortunately, it has a weird behaviour that it takes more than 10 mins to load a single page when connected to the internet. but without internet it loads faster (if i disabled the wifi)
I have seen that it can cause I'm using a .local address. I have tried the followings

1. cleared DNS cache using `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache;sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`
2. adding `::1 myservername.local` hostname to support ipv6
3. switch off ipv6 using the command `networksetup -setv6off Wi-Fi`
4. adding hosts in same line like `127.0.0.1 localhost myservername.local`
5. adding hosts in ipv6 in same line like `::1 localhost myservername.local`
6. added `fe80::1%lo0 localhost` and `fe80::1%lo0 myservername.local`
7. changed `<VirtualHost *:80>` to `<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80>`

still, I'm having the same slowness and nothing worked for me.

Comment: **but without internet it loads faster**, i'm not familiar with drupal but any chance it has auto update feature or similar? any feature that needs to connect to the internet might make it slow as it waits something.

Comment: hmm it is not actually. i feel like something wrong with the DNS resolution over mac. when there is no internet the mysite.local will resolve immediately if not i feel like it goes to check all over DNS entries which is mac redirecting

Comment: oh, if its dns, it is possible dns-over-https causes problem. the thing is, good old dns asks local cache then local dns table before asking to router and isp. but, dns-over-https has tendency to asks the internet first before checking local dns table. maybe you should check its configuration first? there is a [similar problem in the past](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/667347?answerId=682255022#682255022)

Comment: I did this. problem is still there